# Spring Flux: How does the implemenatation pattern look like if i need to make parallel web service calls using Flux and Spring 5

Tags: spring, flux

How does the implemenatation pattern look like if i need to make parallel web service calls using Flux and Spring 5. Basically, my objective is to make multiple web service calls in parallel and stream the content back to browser as and when a web service execution completes.

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the results comming back from those webservices is not relevant, you can use `Flux.merge`.

As per the documentation

> Merge data from Publisher sequences contained in an array / vararg into an interleaved merged sequence.

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#merge-java.lang.Iterable-

If need the order of the values to be the same as the order of the publishers, you can use `Flux.mergeSequential`.

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#merge-java.lang.Iterable-